# What languages would one need to know to do something like this?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to be able to make like.. grids, or spreadsheets, etc.. here are a couple examples..

http://killgrid.com/grid/325

http://demo.warsheet.com/

I want to create a site somewhat similar to those, I would allow users to sign up and create spreadsheets with custom IDs that the owner of the spreadsheet adds through an admin panel..

I write php, but I know that wont be enough to create the website, what would be used to create the design of the spreadsheet and such?

All answers are appreciated.. if you guys could just point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Your question proves, that knowing a language is not enough to build software with it

Answer (score 2):

HTML, and CSS. Those two "languages" combined will allow you to create web pages. By applying HTML "tables", you can create the kinds of "grids" or "spreadsheets" that you showed. Using your PHP skills as well, you will be able to create dynamic tables which change based on your data.

Tutorial:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc

I suggest that you do the HTML one (first link) first.

Hope that helps,

-Sunjay03

Comment: Not at all! It gives a wonderful introduction to HTML and CSS. There is nothing wrong with it. All the information is perfectly valid and useful.

Comment: Much of the information is wrong. The information about HTML is usually wrong in subtle ways that most people won't notice. The information about programming tends to teach people to write code with massive security holes. It is a very long way from wonderful.

Comment: That's not true. Where are these subtle mistakes within the HTML? If you are going to make these claims, at least back them up! Besides, these comments do not contribute to the answer at all. The question was which languages to use, and the answer of HTML and CSS still stands. Where the OP chooses to learn from is their own choice. The options linked here are simply starting points. I have not claimed them to be the ultimate sources for knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad someone was able to provide some evidence. After inspecting the given website, I am convinced of your point.

Answer (score 2):

HTML, images, CSS, and bit of javascript is great combination for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about the pages you link to. To describe the structure of tabular data in HTML, use [tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html). You'll need [forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) to capture the data (and something to process and store the data on the server (a programming language and a database). Then apply [CSS](http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/) for the colour scheming. You don't even need client side JS for this.